# How to repeat equations in functions? (C Programming)

Tags: c, counting

I'm trying to make a basic button press counting program in C for every time a specific button is pressed, "WPAD_BUTTON_A" an equation occurs. "b", which is 1, gets added to the variable, "a", which is 0, and prints it. When it does this, it prints out the answer, but it does not repeat the equation. I am a beginner so this is probably a rookie mistake.

here is my function's code:

```
int main() {

int a, b;
int c;

a = 0;
b = 1;
 
    Initialise();
 
    printf("Clicker v0.02\n");
    
    while(1) {

        WPAD_ScanPads();
        
        u16 buttonsDown = WPAD_ButtonsDown(0);
        
        if( buttonsDown & WPAD_BUTTON_A ) {      
            c = a + b;
            printf(" %d \n", c); 
        }   
        
        if( buttonsDown & WPAD_BUTTON_HOME ) {
            exit(0);
        }
    }
 
    return 0;
}
```

I expected that when the button pressed, it adds one to a and prints that.

An example, of what I want from pressing the button 5 times.

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

However, I would just get this:

```
1
1
1
1
1
```

I would like to get this resolved by Monday.

Comment: a and b never change so every time you add them up it is always 1.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add one to `a`, you should add one to `a`.

Instead of `c = a + b;`, try `c = a = a + b;` or `c = a += b;`.

Comment: Thanks! Can't believe it took me this long to find the issue.